# Google distance Matrix API value insert in Existing XML

Tags: javascript, php, xml, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to insert the Google Distance Matrix API to my existing `xml` data? The `xml` data is produced by my PHP and I don't have an existing travel time included in my Database. I was thiniking if is it possible to upon parsing iteration of my `xml` data the computed travel time and distance of Google Distance Matrix API can be inserted? below is my AJAX call

```
function searchNearMarkers(distance){
    clearLocations();
    document.getElementById('errorNotifs').innerHTML = "";
    //document.getElementById('checkboxes').innerHTML = '';     
    var searchUrl = '...some url here...'
    downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data){
        var xml = parseXml(data);
        var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++){
            var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
            var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
            var info = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("info");
            var budget = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("budget");
            var tts = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("tts");
            var type = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("type");
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));
            distMatLink[i]=(i,markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat"),markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng"));
            bounds.extend(latlng);
            if (i == (markerNodes.length - 1)){
                bounds.extend(userPosLatLng);
            }
        }
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        destinations = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < distMatLink.length ; i++){
        destinations += distMatLink[i];
        }
        var origin = posLat.toFixed(6)+','+posLng.toFixed(6);

        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        service.getDistanceMatrix(
        {
         origins: [origin],
         destinations: [destinations],
         travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING,
         unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
         avoidHighways: false,
         avoidTolls: false
        }, callback);

       function callback(response, status) {
           if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
           var origins = response.originAddresses;
           var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;

           for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
           var results = response.rows[i].elements;
           for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
           var element = results[j];
           var distance = element.distance.text;
           var duration = element.duration.text;
           var from = origins[i];
           var to = destinations[j];
           }
          }
         }
        }
       });
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the  data returned by the DistanceMatrixService?

Comment: I would like to use the travel time computed by the matrix service to subtract it on the initial time input so that I can somehow make what I am doing kinda realistic